# Referencing Qt UIs external to plugin with python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, plugins, qt, pyqt

I'm developing a plugin that sets up a working environment for a user: loading layers (from db), applying styles and several custom designed (Qt) UI files etc.

Primary user interaction is in the Attribute editor (Attribute Table) where there's a mix of Autogenerated and custom designed UIs.

Some of the custom UIs contain Qt objects/widgets that I need to interact with e.g., a QPushButton and a QTabWidget with QWidgets.

Since the plugin is only setting up the working environment, letting the user work freely afterwards, how can I react to user actions/events calling python functionality?

From the following posts I get the notion that my plugin needs to act as the widgets launch platform to be able to send signals and listen on slots.

- [How to reference to my in QT designer created buttons in python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32263/how-to-reference-to-my-in-qt-designer-created-buttons-in-python)
- [Connect not working for custom QGIS form](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67021/connect-not-working-for-custom-qgis-form)

So, in short, I'm trying to interact with custom (Qt) forms external to my plugin.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to access you plugin from the Python Init function file defined under Layer Properties tab Fields that'a controlling your UI. Partly from [The PyQGIS Programmers's Guide](http://locatepress.com/ppg) p. 114:

```
if 'pinpoint' in qgis.utils.plugins:
  pp = qgis.utils.plugins['pinpoint']
  pp.someMethodFromThePlugin
```